# Statistics - Hypothesis Testing

Tags: statistics

The problem is about creating a Hypothesis Testing on the dataset that is divided between two groups: C1 and C2.
In order to prove that taken Null Hypothesis is true, I've calculated:
Mean, standard deriviation, number of test samples for each dataset, value of test statistic z, and finally: p-value.
When it comes to the one-tail test, everything seems to be correct:

```
z = 0.22343
p-value = 0.4116
alpha = 0.05
```

so my null hypothesis is proven.

But whenever it comes to the two tail test, I do obtain something weird:

```
z = 3.97447
p-value = 7.05355
alpha = 0.02
```

As i do remember, p-value should be smaller than 1 and bigger than 0, so it is not correct. I do use almost identical formulas, except for p-value, that in the first example was calculated with the usage of:

```
p-value = F(-|z|)
```

in case of two tail test:

```
p-value = 2*F(-|z|)
```

Does anyone has a clue what is wrong?

Comment: How did you get from $z=0.22343$ to $p$-value $= 0.82320$ ?

Comment: I've taken an absolute value of z, multiplied it by (-1), and then used cumulative density function in order to calculate p-value, so the final form looked like this: p-value = F(-|z|), where F means cumulative density function

Comment: I would have thought $\Phi(-0.22343) \approx 0.4116$.  Did you then double it?

Comment: Oh, well, yes, by a mistake. There was an error in used code. You are totally right when it comes to the one-tail test, but still, values obtained in two tail test are quite unexpected.

Comment: Is there like any probability that p-value would obtain that big number? ( 7.05355 )

Comment: No.  What has happened is you have seen something like `7.05E-05` and read it as about $7.05$ rather than about $7.05\times 10^{-5}=0.0000705$

Comment: By the way, in the first case your null hypothesis is not "proven" (it never is) but "should not be rejected on this evidence"

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much.